# What is the domain of the function $ f:x\mapsto \int_0^1\frac{t^x-1}{\ln(t)}dt$

Tags: improper-integrals

I have been asked to find the domain of the function
$$f:x\mapsto \int_0^1\frac{t^x-1}{\ln(t)}dt$$
where $ x $ is real.

Obviously, $ f(0) $ exists, but for $ x\ne 0$ i couldn't find the criteria to use.

Comment: Technically, "what is the domain" is not the right question.  What you really want to know is, for what (real) values of $x$ does the integral converge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluate
$$
I=\int_0^1 \frac{t^x -1}{\log(t)}dt
$$
using Feynman's trick.
$$
I_{\alpha}=\int_0^1 \frac{t^{\alpha} -1}{\log(t)}dt
$$
$$
\frac{dI_{\alpha}}{d\alpha}=\int_0^1 \frac{d}{d\alpha}
\frac{e^{\alpha \log(t)} -1}{\log(t)}dt=\int_0^1 t^{\alpha}dt
=\frac{1}{\alpha +1}
$$
Thus,
$$
I_{\alpha}= \log(\alpha +1) + C
$$
where $C$ is the constant of integration.  Setting $\alpha =0$ we find $C=0$ and
$$
I=\log(x +1)
$$
For real $I$ we must have $x \gt -1$

Comment: Thanks. How can you differentiate $ I_\alpha $ before knowing its domain ?